# JQuery background animation - is this the right way to do it?

Tags: jquery, animation, background, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get the background of a menu to animate depending on the menu LI

The script I have so far is http://jsfiddle.net/d9LHV/70/

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav ul li').mouseenter(function() {
        var position = $(this).position()
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'backgroundPosition': position.left}, {duration: 150})
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({})
    })
});
```

Seems to work but something feels off about the jQuery but I don't have any jQuery experience and would like some input.

If I use a .hover or take out the .mouseout part the animation becomes jumpy and choppy.

Is there a better way to get the result? Or is something off with my logic, because i don't understand why I need the empty mouseout to make it work smoothly.

Comment: You're missing semi-colons in a few places. Also you don't need `{duration: 150}`, just `150` will do on it's own without the curly brackets. Also the empty `{}` isn't needed in the second `animate()` function.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've cleaned it up a bit but I'm not sure where the semi column should go. I assume one would be after the position variable?

I'm still a bit stumped why it doesn't work without the mouseout or with a hover. I guess it doesn't matter since it's working I just want to learn proper practices when getting into a new library.

Comment: Added an answer as it's easier to show semi-colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason why it gets all jumpy and choppy is because of the multiple animation events fired on the same elements, so it queues all of them up and runs them one after the other.

What you can do is use `.stop()` function before starting another animation, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav ul li').mouseenter(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({'backgroundPosition': position.left}, 150);
    });
});​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pulkitm/d9LHV/71/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! This makes sense now. I Didn't think of .stop and instead was ending the function with the mouseout.

 I knew something didn't fit but couldn't put my finger on it. Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: of-course not. Just click the green check mark on the right, correct?

Comment: Yeah, you checked it. Nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd structure it like this (semi-colons included):

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav ul li').mouseenter(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'backgroundPosition': position.left
        }, 150);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate();
    })
});​
```

Comment: thanks, that's what  jfiddle gave when "tidying up" dropping down the transition time on the next line but for whatever reason it's not working on my local environment.